# War »Komputer« eine forcierte Rechtschreibvariante?

Tags: spelling, history, anglicism

Die vor einigen Jahrzehnten gelegentlich auftauchende Rechtschreibvariante (RSV) *Komputer* hat sich ja nicht durchsetzen können und gilt mittlerweile als nicht mehr korrekt. War das eine RSV, die einfach offiziell eine Weile geduldet wurde oder eine RSV, deren offizieller Zweck es war, *Computer* langfristig zu ersetzen? Wurde diese RSV überhaupt außerhalb der BRD verwendet? Ich hab dazu jetzt noch nichts finden können.

Zum »außerhalb verwendet«: gesehen habe ich die RSV mal in einer in der Schweiz erschienenen Übersetzung; die Übersetzerin war aber Deutsche. 
Google Books legt nahe, dass *Komputer* tatsächlich im gesamten deutschsprachigen Raum verwendet wurde, wenn auch eben selten.

Persönlich finde ich das ja einen Vertreter aus der Kategorie »weder Fisch noch Fleisch«, dann lieber konsequent wie im Französischen ein Ersatzwort.

Comment: Selbst mit der Annahme, dass *RSV* für Rechtschreibvariante steht, erschließt sich mir nicht, was eine *geduldete* oder eine *forcierte* sein soll. Entweder es steht im Duden oder nicht.

Comment: RSV wird wohl Rechtschreibvariante sein...  Zum Thema: Wenn man Computer eindeutschen will, dann nimmt man gleich den Rechner.

Comment: Sorry, ich meinte natürlich Rechtschreibvariante, da hatte ich einfach dict.cc noch im Kopf, wo die Abkürzung RSV verwendet wird. Ich habe den Post nochmal geändert.

Comment: @guidot Dann habe ich mich undeutlich ausgedrückt. Ich meinte mit "forciert" Bestrebungen, es nicht bei der Rechtschreibvariante zu belassen, sondern "Computer" einmal gänzlich zu ersetzen. Durch vorgebenene Richtlinien u.a., jetzt mal allgemein gesprochen.

Comment: Wer soll das denn zu forcieren versucht haben?

Comment: Es gab Anfang der 1980er eine ganze Menge Bücher, in denen tatsächlich durchgehend Komputer geschrieben wurde. Das war aber nie die Regel und wurde auch nie eine.

Comment: @Carsten S Verlage, Sprachgesellschaften, Behörden... Wie gesagt, ich habe mich wohl undeutlich ausgedrückt. Ich meinte nicht unbedingt ein zentrales Durchdrücken, sondern auch mögliche einzelne Akteure.

Comment: Hört sich irgendwie nach Verschwörungstheorie an. Aluhüte raus...

Comment: Sorry, aber leider hat bisher nur die Gegenseite mit skeptics.stackexchange.com eine Community.

Answer (score 5):

Ich sehe für *Komputer* diese Gründe:

- Aussprache
- Import aus Osteuropa / Indonesien
- Schreibfehler (siehe *Standart*)

Nach dem Wälzen praktisch antiker Lexika, wo der *Compiler* noch *Kompilierer* hieß, konnte ich kein einziges Vorkommen in einem Referenzwerk orten. Genutzte Vokabeln waren

- Datenverarbeitungsanlage
- (Tisch-) Rechenanlage
- Digitaler Rechenautomat

Meine Google Books-Treffer fand ich nicht recht überzeugend.

*Forciert*, was immer das bedeuten mag, scheidet für mich damit aus.

Comment: Das mit der Aussprache fiel mir auch sofort auf, als ich _Komputer_ laut vorgelesen habe. Es klingt, als riefe man einen männlichen Truthahn herbei: "_Komm' Puter, komm'! Putt putt putt ..._"

Answer (score 3):

Wer da, mit welcher Absicht, versucht hat das "K" einzuführen, weiß ich nicht.

Praktisch gebraucht wurde die Schreibweise in den Perry Rhodan Romanen der 70er, wo auch andere englischsprachige Begriffe gerne mal hemdsärmlig germanisiert wurden.

Deutsche Science Fiction ist ein faszinierendes Genre.

:-)

Comment: Das Buch "Gespräche mit Seth", wo ich "Komputer" das erste Mal gesehen hatte, ist so sehr Science Fiction wie Perry Rhodan. Da muss es wohl einen Zusammenhang geben.

Answer (score 2):

Es gibt Anfang der 80-er Jahre des letzten Jahrhunderts tatsächlich eine Häufung der Schreibweise *Komputer* in der deutschen Literatur, wie [ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Komputer&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CKomputer%3B%2Cc0) beweist. Die Kurve sieht eindrucksvoll aus und die Schreibweise scheint gängig.

Legt man aber den *Computer* [daneben](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Komputer%2CComputer&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CKomputer%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CComputer%3B%2Cc0), verblasst dieser Eindruck "ein wenig" - gegenüber *Computer* ist die Anzahl der Fundstellen 3 Zehnerpotenzen kleiner - also verschwindend gering.

Stanislav Lem, ein wichtiger Science-Fiction-Autor des letzten Jahrhunderts schrieb natürlich *Komputer* in seiner Heimatsprache Polnisch, manche seiner Übersetzungen haben den Begriff so mitgenommen und machten diese Schreibweise wohl einigermaßen populär (z.B. auch der Begriff "[Skaphander](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skaphander)", den Lem für "Raumanzug" verwendete, vielleicht bevor es wirklich welche gab, war eine zeitlang durchaus verbreitet und die Perry-Rhodan-Romane haben ihn auch verwendet).

Man könnte aufgrund der Schreibweise in den slawischen Sprachen mit "K" jetzt einen "Ost-West-Konflikt" in der deutschen Sprache herbeireden, aber selbst in der damaligen DDR hat sich die Schreibweise außerhalb der Science-Fiction nicht durchgesetzt - Beim [KC85](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleincomputer_KC_85/2-4), einem der ersten DDR-Heimcomputer von 1984, steht das "K" nur für "klein" und das "C" für "Computer".